# Paypal - Things don't appear to be working at the moment

Tags: magento2, paypal-standard

I am using Magento 2 for my website. I have configured Paypal Website Payment Standards. I am testing in sandbox mode. I can receive payment from Paypal account but i can not receive payment from Debit/credit card(Without logging in to paypal). I have enabled Guest Checkout Mode in Magento settings. I have double checked all the settings in Magento and my Paypal Sandbox account but still no solution. Please guide.

Attached is screenshot for the error i get.

[image: Paypal try again]

Comment: you can change it : 
https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/2030-paypal-error-things-dont-appear-to-be-working-at-the-moment

Comment: No it doesn't work for me

Comment: This answer worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126057/10540508